# How to get the nth value of a function with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: functions

I know that I can define a function of a List and get the nth argument like:

```
f[x_List]:=x[[1]]+x[[2]]
```

What if the argument of `f` is not a list? I.e. how to define an equivalent function for

```
f[x__Integer]:=?
```

This is probably extremely basic, but I couldn't figure it out from the `Slot` documentation.

Answer (score 3):

With `f[x__Integer] := ...` you can use

```
{x}[[i]]
```

to get the `i`th argument.

Answer (score 3):

Szabolcs's answer (wrapping the sequence `x` with `List` and using `Part`) is *the* way.

An alternative is to use [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html)

```
ClearAll[f2]

f2[x__Integer] := Indexed[{x}, 1] + Indexed[{x}, 2]
f2[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> 3

You can also use [`Slot (#)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html):

```
ClearAll[f3, f4]

f3[x__Integer] := Slot[1] + Slot[2] &[x]
f3[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> 3

```
f4[x__Integer] := #1 + #2 &[x]
f4[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> 3

but you can use a pure function directly to define your function:

```
f5 = #1 + #2 &
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the pure function method likely to be faster than the Indexed/List methods?

Comment: @user366202, I am not sure.